# Docker Expected Runs in Foreground but Runs in Background

Tags: tomcat, docker

As far as I know, with `-d` option can made Docker Container runs in Daemon or Background, without `-d` option can made Docker Container runs in Foreground and cmd is blocking.

I did little tests:

- Docker Container is made from `tomcat:8.0` Docker Image.
- Docker Container's name `peaceful_allen`  run without `-d`  option.
- Docker Container's name `pensive_lichterman`  run with `-d`  option.
- First `docker ps -a`  command before all cmds are closed.
- Second `docker ps -a`  command after all cmds are closed.
- Third `docker ps -a` command after over 5 minutes all cmds are closed.
- Each Docker Container runs in each cmd.

Result:

1. All Docker Containers are still running after all cmds are closed.

Conclusion:

1. The cmd is not blocking.
2. The Docker Container (especially tomcat's Docker Image) runs in background, because all blocking cmds are closed but Docker Containers are still running.

I expect without `-d` option, when pressing ctrl+c or close cmd the Docker Container is terminated. But the result is not. What's wrong here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The `-d` flag runs the container detached from the terminal where you started it. Without `-d` it remains attached. It has no effect on what's running inside the container, only on whether it stays attached to the terminal session where you launched it. What are you asking?

Comment: I expect without -d, when pressing ctrl + c or closing cmd can terminate Docker Container. Otherwise from that test, the Docker Container is still running.

Comment: The term `cmd` makes me think you are on Windows. I'm not sure what sort of signal closing the `cmd` window on Windows might send to the process inside. On a Mac, closing the terminal window caused the container to exit after a minute or so. I don't have a Windows system handy to do a test, though. It may simply be that closing the `cmd` window doesn't send any sort of kill signal, so the container has no reason to exit.

Comment: But in the docs, its said the cmd will run in foreground and blocking for Docker Container process.